# How can i pass a Query string parameter to my [Remote] data annotation validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

i have an object named `VisitLabResult` that should not have two records with the same `LabTestID and VisitID` ,, so to force this validation i have create a `[remote]` validation on the LabTestID property as follow:-

```
        [Required]
        [Remote("checkexsistence", "VisitLabResult",AdditionalFields= "VisitID")]
        public int LabTestID { get; set; }
```

which will call the following action method:-

```
public JsonResult checkexsistence(int LabTestID, int VisitID)
        {

    var result = repository.checkexsistence(LabTestID, VisitID);
    if (result == null)
    {

        var type = true;
        return Json(type, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
    else {
        var type = false;
        return Json(type, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

and the repository method is :-

```
 public VisitLabResult checkexsistence(int labtestid, int visitid =20)
            {
                return (from vlr in entities.VisitLabResults
                       where (vlr.VisitID == visitid && vlr.LabTestID == labtestid)
                       select vlr).FirstOrDefault();}
```

Currently the `visitid` parameter which is mentioed in the `AdditionalFields= "VisitID"` inside the `Remote` data annotation is found in the query string for calling the CreateGet action method the query string looks as `/VisitLabResult/Create?visitid=20`.

**But the above is not working at all ; no error will be displayed incase the visitid and labtestid are already exists, so how can i fix this ???**

Answer (score 0):

DataAnnotations are more about making sure that the data itself is potentially valid.  You should not be trying to determine uniqueness to the rest of the items in you database with a DataAnnotation.  If you really want to go down this route, I suggest looking into making [custom validators](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx).

Comment: i already set these two fields as unique in the database ,, so it is not risky to do such a validation using the Remote data annotation ,, since if an attacker  bypass the Remote validation then the database will raise an exception ... i did not use the custom validator befre ,, so i am not palnning to use it . BR

Answer (score 0):

Is field VisitID being a part(property) of your model class? The additional field has to be a part of Your model class. For example, if the field Id is in your model(where LabTestID property is) then you shout annotate LabTestID remote like this:

```
[Remote("checkexsistence", "VisitLabResult",AdditionalFields= "Id")]
```